# switch/quit fxml

Tags: javafx, fxml

My test app's flow uses multiple screens :

```
start(Stage stage) -> Screen 1
                   -> Screen 2
                   -> ...
```

I want to implement some of my screens in fxml, but can't figure what's the best practise way to switch between them.

How can i implement some quit-event mechanism in the screen 1 controller, when screen 1 reached its final state, and connect it to the "main loop" to delete screen 1 and update the scene with screen 2 ?

Comment: I do not recomend using FXML, since there is a huge gap of documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way to do it is loading your screens **"on demand"** whenever they are to be used, or even load them for just certain regions of your main screen (like a tab).  To load a screen with FXML and then assign it to your main stage you would do something like:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(me.getClass().getResource("Scene2.fxml"));
Scene scene = new Scene( root );
stage.setScene(scene);
```

Another alternative is to use multiple stages, launch a stage whenever you need to do a specific action.  This stage can be modal, so when it is closed, the main window stays behind:

```
final  Stage stage = new Stage();     
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
stage.initOwner(owner_stage);
stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
```

In this later case, the **"quit mechanism"** is just hiding the scene:

```
// from a label of your controller class
label.getScene().getWindow().hide();
```

In the first case, you would just load the main scene in your stage.  Using multiple stages is the most common and straightforward way.

Comment: But with this multiple stages approach, if the screens are just hidden/switched while being complex with a high number of nodes, all these nodes will remain in memory, right ?

At my level, i've absolutely no clue at how costy this might be ?

If the screens are to be often reused, i guess recreating the nodes would cost more than just keeping all in memory. On the contrary, if the screens are just a linear flow : droped after having been presented to the user, i guess clearing the nodes matters.

Comment: So here comes the question : what this "often" could consist of ? Matter of seconds ? Minutes ? Not a question of time, but another unit ?

I hope i'm clear enough (not that fluent in technical english), and thanx for your first answer.

Comment: For complex applications it is much better to load parts of the screen dynamically or use non-modal dialogs that overlay the main window (see how the ensemble project does it).  It is great how flexible javafx is, everything being a node, you can just set the contents of one node container with a FBML screen you designed visually.  That is the approach I follow for my application using a single stage.   But I figured for a simple project it is easier to just do multiple stages in the same way.